# To what are transistor's "E, B, C" voltages relative to?

Tags: transistors, basic

I've seen \$V_{CE}\$ and \$V_{BE}\$ in context of transistors, where they clearly denote a voltage between two points. But then I also see things such as:

From a [table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bipolar_junction_transistor#Regions_of_operation) in Wikipedia:

```
Applied voltages | B-E junction bias (NPN) | B-C junction bias (NPN) | Mode (NPN)
E < B > C        | Forward                 | Forward                 | Saturation
```

Where do those voltages comes from in a circuit? *"\$V_{E-to-what}\$* **<** *\$V_{B-to-what}\$* **>** *\$V_{C-to-what}\$"*. To my understanding a voltage has to be relative to another point in a circuit, so what are these *E, B and C* relative to?

I've been told I'm missing something. Any ideas?

Comment: Doesn't matter. If the base voltage (relative to the emitter) is positive, and the base voltage (relative to the collector) is positive, then VE-to-anything < VB-to-anything > VC-to-anything (as long as you pick the same "anything" for each measurement)

Comment: Or in other words, Vbe>0 and Vbc>0

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are just comparing the voltages it actually doesn't matter what reference potential you are using, as long as you use the same for each of the 3 voltages.

Using another reference potential would add a constant offset to **all 3** voltages. That woudln't affect the inequaltities.

Comment: +1 for pointing out that the reference point doesn't matter *as long it is **the same** for all three voltages*.

Comment: Now I understood what I was misunderstanding: The equality statement (*E < B > C* for example) should not be read as being voltages in a circuit, but rather as to whether the semiconductor junctions inside the transistor are [forward-](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P%E2%80%93n_junction#Forward_bias) or [reverse-biased](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P%E2%80%93n_junction#Reverse_bias).

Answer (score 5):

It doesn't actually matter (since all electrovoltaic potentials are relative regardless), but the easiest way to interpret them is relative to each other. When the relation described is true, the transistor is in the given state.

Answer (score 4):

Yes you are correct. The voltage has to be relative to another point in the circuit. If the reference node is not mentioned in the symbol, then it means that the reference node is ground.

So \$V_E\$ denotes the voltage at emitter with respect to the common reference, the voltage at *ground* node.

Comment: Originally I had accepted Curd's answer, but at that time all three of the the answers seemed so close to each other that I chose yours, as it answered my question exactly and was the most legs-on-the-ground. Now I have understood why Curd's answer is the correct one and have also added a comment to his answer regarding my confusion.

Answer (score 3):

Transistors can be used in very simple circuits where there is clearly a 'ground' (e.g. a NPN's E is connected directly to 'ground'), but they can also be used deep within a complex circuit where 'ground' or even 'Vcc' is not directly connected (there's several other components inbetween).

This is why "Vce" (or "Vbc", etc), for example, means "the maximum permissible voltage *between C & E*", *reagardless* of what the voltage of C & E is with respect to 'ground'.

If you do see a reference to 'Vc' or 'Vb' (for example), then it's implied that it's with respect to 'ground'.

Same perspective applies to MOSFETs' G, D & S.

Answer (score 2):

Almost all modern equipment relates these single-point references to a supply rail which is regarded as the common or ground. This is typically the negative on single supplies, or the mid point on dual +- supplies.

Note that this point is not necessarily at earth potential, in the sense of building earth. It is simply a convenient reference point. Thus, it should NOT be assumed that it is always OK to connect any earthed piece of test equipment (such as a 'scope) to this point.

Answer (score 0):

`E < B > C` can be interpreted as

- Potential of B is bigger than the others. This means that if you connect B with any of the others with a resistor, current will flow towards "the others" through the resistor.

  This means as well that `V_{BE} > 0` and `V_{BC} > 0`.
- Voltage between B and any freely chosen reference point is bigger than the voltage between E or C and the same reference point.